# Turtle() only listening to onkeypress one time, not repeating keys

Tags: python, user-interface, screen, turtle-graphics, listen

so I am making snake and whenever I call my key press it works fine just one time. I can go up once, down once, right and left all exactly one time. But if I want to use this key to change direction again I cannot, anyone know why? Here is my code (also mainloop causes my turtle not to show):

```
from turtle import *
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
import random 
import time 

screen = Screen() ## the window that shows up

screen.setup(800,800) ## height and width to 800
screen.bgcolor("black") ## black GUI
screen.title("G5's Snake Game") ## name our game 
screen.tracer(0) ## eliminates delay from snake, molds it all into one picture

snake = Snake()

screen.onkeypress(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkeypress(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkeypress(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(snake.right, "Right")
screen.listen()
screen.listen()


gameon = True 

while gameon: ## make this snake.move() method !    
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    snake.move()




screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Please show your `Snake` class.

Answer (score -1):

```
screen.onkeypress(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkeypress(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkeypress(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(snake.right, "Right")
screen.listen()
screen.listen()
```

The block above needs to be moved into a while loop.
Right now, it will check if the user ever presses a key. If they do, it will move down to the while loop.

```
while gameon:
    screen.onkeypress(snake.up, "Up")
    screen.onkeypress(snake.down, "Down")
    screen.onkeypress(snake.left, "Left")
    screen.onkeypress(snake.right, "Right")
    screen.listen()
    screen.listen()
```

Comment: This isn't true. Registering listeners needs only to be done one time. There's no point in calling `screen.listen()` twice.

Comment: I am using there code though

Comment: But their code is wrong. The problem with their post is something other than what's been shown. They haven't produced a [mcve]. Moving the listeners into the loop is a step in the wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

try to use screen.onkey(..) and  put screen.listen() before it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The order of `listen()` and `onkeypress()` doesn't matter